# Irreducibility using reduction mod $p$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials, unique-factorization-domains

I know that if $R$ is a UFD and $\mathfrak{p} \subset R$ a prime ideal and $f$ a polynomial in $R[X]$ with content 1, s.t. $\deg(f)=\deg(\bar{f})$ then:

$\bar{f}$ is irreducible in $R/\mathfrak{p}[X] \Rightarrow$ f is irreducible in $R[X]$

(where $\bar{f}$ is $f$‘s image under the canonical homomorphism $R[X] \rightarrow R/\mathfrak{p}[X] $).

I‘ve now come upon the following example:

With $f=X^5+4X^2+14X+40 \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ we get:

$\bar{f} = (X^3+2X+1)(X^2+1)$ in $\mathbb{Z}/(3)[X] $ and
$\bar{f} = (X^4+4X+4)X$ in $\mathbb{Z}/(5)[X] $

Now since one is a decomposition into polynomials of degree 3 and 2 and the other one into polynomials of degree 4 and 1 $f$ must be irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$.

I dont quite understand why this works. I get that $f=gh$ in $R[X]$ induces a decomposition $\bar{f}=\bar{g}\bar{h}$ in $R/\mathfrak{p}[X]$ with $\deg(g)=\deg(\bar{g}),\deg(h)=\deg(\bar{h})$. So if the decomposition in $R/\mathfrak{p}[X]$ were unique an existing decomposition like $\bar{f}=\bar{g}\bar{h}$ with $\deg(\bar{h})=3, \deg(\bar{g})=2$ would imply that $f$ is either irreducible in $R[X]$ or can only be decomposed as a product of a polynomial of degree 3 and one of degree 2. But while $R[X]$ is a UFD, how do we know that $R/\mathfrak{p}[X]$, or rather $R/\mathfrak{p}$ is one (which would have to be the case s.t. such a decomposition would have to be unique).

A quick search shows me that whether $R/\mathfrak{p}$ is a UFD is a rather complicated question, so I must be missing some simpler argument. Any help is appreciated:)

Comment: The $\mathfrak p$ in your case is either the maximal ideal $(3)$ or $(5)$, so $R/\mathfrak p$ is a field. So $R/\mathfrak p[x]$ is actually a PID and hence a UFD.

Comment: Easier to check the factorization in $Frac(R/\mathfrak{p})[X]$ instead of $R/\mathfrak{p}[X]$

Comment: @Arkady Ohh I forgot about that theorem, thank you!! So then this methods always works because in UFD‘s prime Ideal‘s are automatically maximal?

Comment: Careful: prime ideals in a UFD are not automatically maximal. $(2) \subset \mathbb{Z}[x]$ is a prime ideal since $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(2) \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and this is an integral domain, but $(2)$ is not maximal since this ring is not a field.

Comment: Right:  irreducible $\Leftrightarrow$ prime in UFD‘s but prime ideal $\Leftrightarrow$ max ideal only in PID‘s. So it works if $R$ is a PID because then $R/\mathfrak{p}$ is a field and thus $R/\mathfrak{p}[X]$ is a UFD?

Comment: If your question is "is $R/\frak{p}$$[x]$ a UFD?", then yes, $R$ a PID and $\frak{p}$ a prime implies $R/\frak{p}$$[x]$ a UFD (indeed, it implies something much stronger: that $R/\frak{p}$$[x]$ is a Euclidean domain).

Comment: I'm not sure about your claim that "$f=gh$ in $R[X]$ induces a decomposition $\bar{f}=\bar{g}\bar{h}$ in $R/\mathfrak{p}[X]$ with $\deg(g)=\deg(\bar{g}),\deg(h)=\deg(\bar{h})$. For example, take $f = 2x^3 + x = x(2x^2 + 1)$. Then in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}[x]$ this is the polynomial $x$, hence cannot be written as a product of a degree 2 polynomial and a degree 1 polynomial. Also, in $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}[x]$ it factors as $x(2x^2 + 1)$, but the difference in the degree of $f$'s factors modulo $2$ and $3$, respectively, clearly doesn't imply that $f$ is irreducible.

Comment: Yes it only holds if the condition at the beginning of the question „$\deg(f)=\deg(\bar{f})$“ holds. Sorry, I should have written this again.

Comment: no, no, no, that's my fault for not reading closely enough! : )